# Widget options doesn't return anything

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to get data from my widget options but only get the serialized response, this is my code:

```
include('wp-config.php');
include("wp-blog-header.php");

$options = get_option('widget_muro');
var_dump($options);
```

return:

```
a:1:{s:12:"_multiwidget";i:1;}
```

and

```
echo $options['name'];
```

returns nothing

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Use [unserialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) to convert it into an array.

```
$options = 'a:1:{s:12:"_multiwidget";i:1;}';
$options = unserialize($options);
echo $options['_multiwidget']; //1
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer dkruchok!, i run the code, but save other settings in the options. This is the code I use to save

```
function update($new_instance, $old_instance){          
        $instance = $old_instance;           
        $instance['nombre'] = sanitize_text_field($new_instance['nombre']);
        $instance['servidor'] = sanitize_text_field($new_instance['servidor']);        
        return $instance;          
    }

    function form($instance){           
        $defaults = array('nombre' => '', 'servidor'=> '');           
        $instance = wp_parse_args((array)$instance, $defaults);            
        $nombre = $instance['nombre'];
        $servidor = $instance['servidor'];
        ?>
        <p>
            Nombre
            <input class="widefat" type="text" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('nombre');?>"
                   value="<?php echo esc_attr($nombre);?>"/>
        </p>
        <p>
            Servidor
            <input class="widefat" type="text" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('servidor');?>"
                   value="<?php echo esc_attr($servidor);?>"/>
        </p>        
<?php        
    }
```

Comment: So, what the question?